# Can a DIY rocket put an object into a stable orbit around earth?

Tags: amateur-rocketry, model-rocketry, hybrid-rocket

Is it possible for a "home made" rocket to launch an object into a stable orbit assuming a person has calculated the right trajectory?

Comment: Charles Pooley had the idea of microlauchers, really miniature spacecrafts launched with crude rockets within a bachelor's household budget. [A video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtTeG_HElNk) And [one of the reviews](http://www.thespacereview.com/article/2461/1) It didn't happen so I don't know if it is doable.